# App store rejects my app developed in expo although the app works completely fine while testing

Tags: ios, app-store, expo

App store rejects my app developed in expo although the app works completely fine while testing.

**This is the message i get from apple:**

**"We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 11.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
When user launches the app, app displays an error message.
Please see attached screenshots for details."
[image: This is the screenshot apple store sent me]
**

I have tested my app and it works completely fine in iOS 11.1. I tested in development mode and as well as without development mode.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2431/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just tell that you can't test on an IPV6 network, and for know is fully working in IPV4. (It worked for me)

Apple is starting to prepare for a  world where IPV4 "doesn't exist".
But not everybody has a proper environment for testing networking request on IPV6 layer.

Comment: Will Apple accept my app if it's not tested on an IPv6 network and is fully working on an IPv4 network?

Comment: Yes. But you may first have to say that you don't have a fully capable way to test IPV6.